# Minimalizing a menu with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json

I know the question title is a little vague but I don't know what else to call it. Basically, this is my problem:

I have an angular menu with submenus. I have each menu item separate and the submenu items being injected with ng-repeat. That is fine, but the problem is I would like to run the entire menu in one ng-repeat and have the json file hold, not only the submenu items, but the menu items as well. This is what I have:

```
<div class="cnt">
    <div class="menu-item" ng-click="toggle(1); open1=!open1">
        <md-list layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
            <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item</span>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-class="{'rotate180': open1, 'rotate-back': !open1}"></i>
        </md-list>
        <div class="sub-menu" ng-animate="'animate'" >
            <md-menu-item ng-if="menuIsOpen===1" ng-repeat="item in data"  >
                <md-button>
                    <div layout="row" flex="">
                        <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                            <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item" ng-click="toggle(2); open2=!open2">
        <md-list layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
            <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item 2</span>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-class="{'rotate180': open2, 'rotate-back': !open2}"></i>
        </md-list>
        <div class="sub-menu" ng-animate="'animate'" >
            <md-menu-item ng-if="menuIsOpen===2" ng-repeat="item in data2">
                <md-button>
                    <div layout="row" flex="">
                        <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                            <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with a json file that looks like this:

```
$scope.data = 
    [{
        title: 'Home',
        icon: 'home',
        link: '/page1/'
    }, {
        title: 'Email Us',
        icon: 'envelope',
        link: '/page2/'
    }, {
        title: 'Profile',
        icon: 'user',
        link: '/page3/'
    }, {
        title: 'Print',
        icon: 'print',
        link: '/page4/'
    }];

$scope.data2 = 
    [{
        title: 'Home 2',
        icon: 'home',
        link: '/page1/'
    }, {
        title: 'Email Us 2',
        icon: 'envelope',
        link: '/page2/'
    }, {
        title: 'Profile 2',
        icon: 'user',
        link: '/page3/'
    }, {
        title: 'Print 2',
        icon: 'print',
        link: '/page4/'
    }];
```

As you can see, if I want 2 menu items, I have to build the code for 2 menu items, add the data to the json, and run the bindings. And if I want 3, then I have to do this 3 times. But what if I want 20? Ideally, I would like to have 1 single HTML structure that pulls the data from the json to create as many menu items with as many submenu items as it finds in the json. But I am having problems trying to achieve this:

This is what makes sense in my head:

```
<div class="cnt" ng-repeat="item in data">
    <div class="menu-item" ng-click="toggle({{item.pos}}); open{{item.pos}}=!open{{item.pos}}">
        <md-list layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
            <span class="title flex" flex=""> {{item.name}}</span>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-class="{'rotate180': open{{item.pos}}, 'rotate-back': !open{{item.pos}}}"></i>
        </md-list>
        <div class="sub-menu" ng-animate="'animate'" >
            <md-menu-item ng-if="menuIsOpen==={{item.pos}}" >
                <md-button>
                    <div layout="row" flex="">
                        <a ui-sref="{{item.item1[0].linkto}}">
                            <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.item1[0].title}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/qRVOew?editors=1010) that you can see the working code in.

See this [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/pRNLwo?editors=1010) for the desired effect. This is how I have it working now and how it should work ultimately.

Thanks fellas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is not directly addressing the parsing issue, but a solution to what you are trying to achieve.
Instead of using `open{{item.pos}}` to identify the menu item, which is resulting in parsing error, use the the `menuIsOpen`,which holds the position of the toggled item. Based on the desired effect.. [codepen sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgyvGe?editors=1010)

script additions

```
//Not needed
// $scope.open1 = false; //initial value
//$scope.open2 = false; //initial value
//$scope.open3 = false; //initial value
//$scope.open4 = false; //initial value

$scope.toggle = function(itemPos) {
    if ($scope.menuIsOpen === itemPos) {
        $scope.menuIsOpen = 0; 
    }
    else {
        $scope.menuIsOpen = itemPos;  
    }
}
```

html : just need toggle the `item` we pass the position property

```
<div class="cnt" ng-repeat="item in data">
    <div class="menu-item" ng-click="toggle(item.pos);">
        <md-list layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
            <span class="title flex" flex=""> {{item.name}}</span>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-class="{'rotate180': item.pos==menuIsOpen, 'rotate-back': !menuIsOpen}"></i>
        </md-list>



        <div class="sub-menu" ng-animate="'animate'" >
            <md-menu-item ng-if="menuIsOpen===item.pos" >
                <md-button>
                    <div layout="row" flex="">
                        <a ui-sref="{{item.item1[0].linkto}}">
                            <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.item1[0].title}} a</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Let us know

---

Update : based on your comment, the current setup only deals with item at postion 0 (only 1 item). The JSON (if you do not have control) and you need the item1 item2 etc.. to be displayed you can extend the ng-repeat by going over the entire object and iterate ONLY the ARRAYS. This is not going for the optimal solution just a work around.. sort of..

If there is another array of links inside the array.. this solution will not work.

html

```
<div class="sub-menu" ng-animate="'animate'" >
    <div ng-repeat='(k,v) in item track by $index'>
        <div ng-if="isArray(v)">
            <md-menu-item ng-if="menuIsOpen===item.pos" ng-repeat='v1 in v track by $index'>                        
                <md-button>
                    <div layout="row" flex="">
                        <a ui-sref="{{v1.linkto}}">
                            <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{v1.icon}}"></i> {{v1.title}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </md-button>    
            </md-menu-item>
        </div>
    </div>              
</div>
```

script

```
$scope.isArray = function(val) {
    return Array.isArray(val);
}
```

Comment: Outstanding! I love it. Great work. One thing tho...how come the submenu items are not being injected. The menu items name do, but each menu should have a couple of submenus in them and they're not passing through. I'm assuming is a json structure problem?

Comment: @LOTUSMS I've updated answer by checking my answer it this time. Sorry about that.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Thank you. This will make everything much smoother and I can replicate this on other menus as well. Life saver

Comment: Ta :) You should check this out.. This might be of some help.. http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/